# Minification of internal typescript modules with webpack / uglifyJS

Tags: typescript, webpack, bundling-and-minification, uglifyjs

My project is using internal typescript modules, it basically consists of one big module `project` with lots of sub modules `project.sub.etc`.
With `tsc --out` this is compiled into a `bundle.js`, which when loaded automatically makes `project` available as a global variable.

Now I want to minify my bundle. For the rest of the project I rely on webpack a lot, so I tried to setup a webpack config to minify the generated bundle. For that I used the uglyfiJS plugin which comes with webpack. However when I load the generated `bundle.min.js` **the global module is not available in the global scope**.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: project is not defined
```

How come and how can I fix this?

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./builds/bndle.js",
    output: {
        path: "./builds",
        filename: "bundle.min.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            mangle:false
        })
    ]
};
```

I already tried turning off mangling, because I thought that would change the name of the modules, but it didn't help.

I also tried adding

```
output: {
   libraryTarget: "var",
   library: "Foo"
}
```

to the webpack config. This gives me a globl `project` variable, but it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: project is not defined

Are you sure the JavaScript is loaded?. You do have a typo in your code:

```
entry: "./builds/bndle.js"
```

Quoting you :

> this is compiled into a bundle.js, which when loaded automatically

Fix:

```
entry: "./builds/bundle.js"
```